# jQuery .load function makes script only excecute once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to use jQuery's `.load` function to load a div element from one page to another. But it makes the whole script only run once.

I've seen a few similar question here on SO, but none of these seem to fit my problem. I've tried things such as changing `.click` to `.one` as well as adding `new Date().getTime()` and `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})` to prevent cashing. None these works.

I'm not sure what the problem is, but it seem to occur only when I use the `.load` function. I've attached a simplified version of my `script.js` file below:

---

**script.js**

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

        $("body").load(url + " .container");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>This is the index page</h2>
        <a href="index.html">Index page</a>
        <br>
        <a href="second.html">Second page</a>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `second.html` looks pretty much the same as the `index.html` file.

Comment: syntax error on: `$("a").click(function(e)
        var url = $(this).attr("href");` -> change to `$("a").click(function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");`

Comment: The script doesn't run only once. It starts running then crashes because of the syntax error. _Open your console_, it's telling you everything.

Comment: @messerbill Sorry, typo. Looks like I removed the `{` by mistake when I posted the code here.

Comment: so what do you expect to happen after the load was executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handlers are only bound to the anchors on the first page, I would use event delegation so that I would not have to bind the handlers every time a new page is loaded.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    $("body").load(url + " .container");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just make sure to add a `{` after the `.on` function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it with calling the Javascript after the `load()` again. Here is the snippet

```
$.getScript('<your script>');
```